# Take over the WPF app startup process

Tags: wpf, bootstrapping

I have a bootstrap class that currently exists in my WPF project. It sets up my Autofac dependencies and some abstract factory methods of mine. This bootstrap class *is not* the same bootstrap that is used in Prism/Unity.

What I want to do is clean up my dependency graph a bit.

[image: Dependency Graph]

I can clean up a lot of this by removing the dependencies that `Pen.Apps.Desktop.exe` has on all of the other assemblies. Those dependencies exist due to the DI setup taking place in that project. Instead, I want to refactor that setup out in to an independent project called App.Bootstrap. The `App.Bootstrap` project will reference all of the dependencies, set up the DI and then start up the `.App.Desktop`. This way, `App.Desktop` only has a dependency on three libraries, my domain, my presentation and my service interface project.

I've done this before in WinForms, just by having a main method in one project that spins up a form from another project. In WPF however, it seems to be a bit trickier. I need to run the sub-classed Application (app.xaml.cs); I can't seem to find any way of doing that though.

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    static Form mainWindow;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var penApp = new Pen.Apps.Desktop.App();
    }
}
```

The `penApp` instance only has one public method, `InitializeComponent`. The `Run()` method found on the static `Application` class does not seem to exist. I don't want to just do `Application.Run(new MainWindow());` as there is stuff in my app.xaml.cs that needs to run (and should stay there).

Another option I have looked at is making the `Bootstrapper` class static, and implementing a simple pub/sub system. Let the app.xaml.cs publish with the app.xaml.cs instance and the bootstrap class receive it. The bootstrap class can then setup DI and callback in to the app.xaml.cs when it is finished. That's an option; I'm looking for something a little more tightly coupled if I could.

Anyone done this before, or have an idea as to how I can go about taking over the startup process of a WPF app?

Answer (score 1):

Can you avoid depending on DI in your `App` class? If the answer is mostly "yes" you could override `OnStartup()` which is called and returns before your main window is constructed. So long as you're not constructing or doing anything that depends on DI before then you should be good. Note that this depends on execution order in the framework so obviously that could change on you in the future (but likely won't, I imagine).

*Sidebar:*
A bootstrapper could actually create an instance of your `App` class and call `Run()` on it (`new App().Run()`) as it appears to be how it's normally done....

**Update:**
Here you go, this one works. I did it in the same assembly but your bootstrapper could be in its own assembly; be sure to point the project at your custom entry point on the "Application" page of project settings.

```
using System;

namespace TryStartup
{
    public class Bootstrapper
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // Your initialization code here...

            var app = new TryStartup.App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, when I do `new App()`, the only method available to me is `InitializeComponent`. Are you doing this from a different assembly? The issue that I have is a circular reference. My bootstrap assembly needs to reference classes in the Desktop project, so the Desktop project can not call in to the bootstrap project to tell it i'm starting.

Comment: This is all within one assembly, .NET 4.5, VS 2013. My `App` inherits from `System.Windows.Application`. The WPF app normally starts from `Application.Run()`--you can see that if you override `OnStartup()` and set a breakpoint there, check out the call stack.

Comment: Ah ok. I am wanting to break the two different assemblies